# Can't figure out cause of service_identity module error

Tags: python, windows, scrapy

Error is:

`UserWarning: You do not have a working installation of the service_identity module: 'cannot import name 'verify_ip_address' from 'service_identity.pyopenssl' (C:\Users\techn\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\service_identity\pyopenssl.py)'.  Please install it from <https://pypi.python.org/pypi/service_identity> and make sure all of its dependencies are satisfied.  Without the service_identity module, Twisted can perform only rudimentary TLS client hostname verification.  Many valid certificate/hostname mappings may be rejected.`

I've tried all other possible answers from several sites but none of them fix my problem. Any insight?

I've tried:

```
pip install cryptography
pip install cffi --upgrade
pip install service_identity --upgrade
pip install pyopenssl --upgrade
```

Comment: Show us how you run the code.  (i.e. do you type something on a command line, or run from a GUI, etc.)

Comment: Can you try `pip show service_identity`? Is it located in `Anaconda3/lib/site-packages`? Maybe the pip you are running is installing it somewhere else (not Anaconda's packages)

Comment: @JohnGordon I use ```scrapy crawl kycspider``` from Anaconda prompt

Comment: @FilipDimitrovski here is the output:


```(base) C:\Users\techn\scrapy\KYCSpider\KYCSpider\spiders>pip show service_identity
Name: service-identity
Version: 18.1.0
Summary: Service identity verification for pyOpenSSL & cryptography.
Home-page: https://service-identity.readthedocs.io/
Author: Hynek Schlawack
Author-email: hs@ox.cx
License: MIT
Location: c:\users\techn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
Requires: attrs, pyasn1-modules, pyasn1, cryptography
Required-by: Scrapy```

Comment: Is `pip` the correct way to install packages for Anaconda?

Comment: @JohnGordon I'm not sure, I'm new to python and Anaconda, I saw something about ```conda``` somewhere but i dont know how to install service_identity using it.

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out, I needed to:

`pip install service-identity`
(prefered, much more recent version) or

`conda install -c conda-forge service_identity` (a now obsolete version from 2019)